# How to use fn:replace() to replace one doublequote by two doublequotes

Tags: jsf-2, el

In my JSF application I am trying to use `fn:replace()` to replace `"` by `""`. I tried the following:

```
<h:outputText value="#{fn:replace(str, '\"', '\"\"')}" />
```

However, it causes a XML parsing exception:

> javax.faces.view.facelets.FaceletException: Error Parsing /test.xhtml: Error Traced[line: 20] Element type "h:outputText" must be followed by either attribute specifications, ">" or "/>".

The same code is working for other charecters like the below one:

```
<h:outputText value="#{fn:replace(str, 'a', 'b')}" />
```

How can I replace a doublequote by two doublequotes using `fn:replace()`?

Comment: That's not regex based replacement. That's just character based replacement. It's exactly like you're using `String#replace()` method, not `replaceAll()` method. Please do not confuse them. I removed the incorrect references to regex from your question.

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, this is nasty. The `"` has special treatment in XML. It represents the start and end of an attribute value.  Your best bet is to parameterize it into another variable with help of `<c:set>`.

```
<c:set var="doublequote" value='"' />
<c:set var="twodoublequotes" value='""' />
<h:outputText value="#{fn:replace(bean.string, doublequote, twodoublequotes)}" />
```